# Migrating from Postgresql 9.1 (non drupal) to Percona Server 5.5

Tags: 7, database, migrations

We decided to go from a perl website to Drupal 7 (PHP 5.5.23).

My big question is how do i migrate the DB which is PSQL 9.1 to mySQL. I've heard of the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module, Drush, MySQL Workbench.

Can someone direct me on which steps to take after converting my postgresql schema to  mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I end up using the feeds importers modules. You may have to change (rewrite/delete) your tables.

1. dump my table in a csv file (*.csv) make sure to add the headers.
2. create a content type with the name of my table and have all the columns of my tables
3. create a feed importer make sure to map the sources (postgreql) and target (drupal mysql) columns
4. got the import link (homepage/import) to upload the file. this may take a few minutes depending on how big you DB is.
5. when you go to content you should see all the newly added rows

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to migrating such Postgress database, you may want to go for a co-existence approach (which eventually you can still migrate later on). To do so, have a look at the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it). It can be used to  build reports and/or charts about data stored in your existing Postgress database. Here is a quote about Forena:

> ... built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.

The advantage of this approach is that you get lots of Drupal features available, while the "backend-part" of your application continues to be the applicationn you already have (you don't loose the investements made in that).